# How do I make my website cross-browser compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

my website is properly work in google chrome but not work in other web-browser .
index page design not in proper manner. plzs give some solution fast

css not proper work on other browser

Comment: Give screenshots

Comment: add this script in your page and you will get same behaviour for all browser `<script>document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "none";</script>`

Comment: You should hire someone.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and edit your question.

Answer (score -1):

Add your css inside the below curly brace for Mozilla,

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

}
```

for IE add the below one.

```
<!--[if IE]>

<style>

  .x{



  }...
```